# Поиск всех соседних точек в многомерном пространстве

Tags: алгоритм

На входе есть координаты точки, на выходе - нужно вывести координаты всех соседних точек (прямых и по диагонали). Например для двух измерений и точки [0, 0] это будет (для наглядности разбил на строки):

```
[[ 1,-1], [1, 0], [1, 1]

[ 0,-1], [0, 0], [0, 1]

[-1,-1], [-1,0], [-1,1]]
```

Проблема в том, что количество измерений может быть не 1 или 2, а до 6. Соответственно хотелось бы узнать, какой алгоритм использовать в функции для вывода соседних точек вместо 6 вложенных циклов?

Под соседними точками понимаются точки одна или несколько координат которых отличаются на единицу (один "шаг") от точки на входе.

Comment: Посмотрите, что говорят правила оформления вопросов для учебных заданий, на тему как не нарваться на грубость.

Comment: Я думаю это можно легко сделать с помощью рекурсии:)

Comment: @pavel да, чувствую что нужна рекурсия но пока что нет понимания куда двигаться.

Comment: @rad, чтобы получить помощь, Вам нужно основательно отредактировать свой вопрос. Здесь не принято делать чужую работу. Объясните, что Вы пытались делать и у Вас не получилось

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов не могу придумать сам алгоритм.

Comment: Пока вопрос не адекватен, сформулируйте строго, что такое соседние точки.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов в примере видно, что это все точки отстоящие на -1,0,+1 по каждому измерению. Или вы усматриваете в чем-то альтернативный вариант?

Comment: Я профессиональный математик пока не могу понять задачу. Пример - это иллюстрация, нормальная постановка задачи - это 90 процентов решения, уверен, что если автор вопроса сможет внятно объяснить, что он хочет - помощь ему уже будет не нужна.

Comment: Прервусь на 40 минут

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов неудобно признаваться, но мне постановка задачи вполне ясна .. Расскажите, в чем может быть подвох? Не стесняйтесь пожалуйста задавать автору уточняющие вопросы и обозначать неясные места!

Comment: @Kromster спасибо за помощь, ответ я все-таки нашел, так что видимо вопрос удалю.

Comment: @rad не удаляйте! Лучше наоборот напишите свой ответ - вдруг еще кому поможет!

Comment: @Kromster, мне нужно было, чтобы автор сказал, что не знает как построить n-мерный гиперкуб , в заданной точке с единичными ребрами. После этого он смог бы решить задачу без посторонней помощи.

Answer (score 4):

У Вас есть некоторая центральная точка с координатами X(x<sub>0</sub>, x<sub>1</sub>, ... x<sub>n</sub>) Тогда все соседние точки будут иметь координаты Y(Y<sub>0</sub>, Y<sub>1</sub>, ... Y<sub>n</sub>), где Y<sub>k</sub> будет принимать каждое значение из списка [х<sub>k</sub> - 1, х<sub>k</sub>, х<sub>k</sub> + 1]

Т.е. Все искомые точки мы можем представить как набор n-разрядных чисел в троичной системе исчисления. Где минимальное число будет (x<sub>0</sub> - 1, x<sub>1</sub> - 1, ... x<sub>n</sub> - 1), а максимальное (x<sub>0</sub> + 1, x<sub>1</sub> + 1, ... x<sub>n</sub> + 1)

Как происходит прибавление единицы к числу в n-ричной системе исчисления? Смотрят, на значение младшего разряда. Если он меньше, чем n - 1, то просто прибавляют к нему 1. Если же равен, то сбрасывают его в 0, а 1 прибавляют к следующему разряду. Таким образом, операция прибавления 1 оказывается рекурсивной.

Т.к. мы работаем только с n-разрядными числами, то если нам нужно будет сбросить в 0 самый старший разряд, то считаем, что все числа закончились

```js
function incPoint(APoint, ACenterPoint, ADim) {
  APoint[ADim]++;
  if (APoint[ADim] > ACenterPoint[ADim] + 1) {
    if (ADim == APoint.length - 1)
      return false;
    APoint[ADim] = ACenterPoint[ADim] - 1;
    return incPoint(APoint, ACenterPoint, ADim + 1);
  }
  return true;
}

var centerPoint = [0, 0, 0];
var curPoint = new Array(centerPoint.length);
for (var i = 0; i < curPoint.length; i++)
  curPoint[i] = centerPoint[i] - 1;
var idx = 1;
do {
  console.log(idx + ': ' +JSON.stringify(curPoint));
  idx++;
} while (incPoint(curPoint, centerPoint, 0))
```

Comment: @Kromster, встряну в разговор двух уважаемых донов. Вы думаете автор вопроса, которому "...нужно в псевдокоде...", сможет в этом ответе что-нибудь понять? ИМХО, продуктивнее заминусовать плохой вопрос, не трогая это иезуитский ответ :)

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов а вариант подсказать вообще не рассматривается? Я понимаю что не местный и такие как я тут пачками плодят тупые вопросы но можно ведь написать пару слов чтобы направить в нужную сторону?

Comment: @Kromster Вы легко можете пометить ответ тревогой и потребовать у модератора его удаления

Comment: @rad Что непонятно в моем ответе?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov честно говоря слишком умный для меня :) Я бы углубился и попытался это реализовать но нашелся вариант проще. Но спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос можно переформулировать "нужны все возможные комбинации комбинации -1, 0 и 1 размерностью N".
Для этого можно воспользоваться функцией product() из библиотеки itertools в питоне.

```
import itertools
N = 3
result = list(itertools.product([-1,0,1], repeat=N))
```